# Adding whitespace nowrap breaks css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with 2 columns and i want to add an element inside the 2 column grid that will have an ellipsis if it is too long. But when I add `whitespace: nowrap;` to the css it breaks the grid columns. Why and is there a way to fix it?

Simple example with nowrap:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

span{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simple example without nowrap:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

span{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the second example there are 2 even columns but in the first example there it breaks out through the right side of the body. Also I do want to be able to add more content to the div. So I only want the ellipsis for the span.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `overflow: hidden` und `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the div itself.

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

span{  
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I actually want to put more content into this div so I would like the text two wrap if I add say a `<p>` to the div. I only want the ellipsis for the `<span>`. I will edit the question to be more clear.